# iphone: 8 tool bar items?

Tags: iphone, toolbar, uitoolbaritem

How do I implement a swipe for the 7th and 8th tool bar item so they display?

Comment: It sounds like you want a scrolling toolbar so to speak, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes... the problem with what I currently have (UITabBarController) is that I lose track of which tab the user tapped.  (I have more than 5, therefore have that "more" button which takes me to a hierarchy which is not necessary.  If I could figure out a way to "swipe" the tab bar, I'd be a happy camper!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your items on a `UIScrollView` with a contentSize wider than the toolbar. Probably want to make it the width of all 8 buttons, *plus space between*.

Alternatively, [`Three20`](https://github.com/facebook/three20) has something similar.

Comment: You should revise your question if you in fact are referring to a `UITabBar`. By default, the UITabBar will add a **More** button that displays tabs if there are more than 5.

Comment: I know that... that's NOT what I want... it creates a hierarchy which is unnecessary.  I think your idea of a UIScrollView might work as a last resort... :D